# Como Criar um Submenu Slide Side Out

Tags: ios, objective-c

Como posso adicionar um submenu a um menu existente, exemplo tenho o menu `Ensino` dentro de ensino quero colocar `Cursos`,`Intercambio` e `iniciação cientifica`, estou usando uma classe chamada `SWRevealViewController`  e no menu uso uma `tableView`, esta assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa funcionalidade deve ser implementada na própria tableView.

Existem várias bibliotecas que implementam essa funcionalidade de expandir e encolher células em um tableView, também conhecido como *accordion*.

Uma que considero bastante simples de usar é [SLExpandableTableView](https://github.com/OliverLetterer/SLExpandableTableView)
Ela extende a classe UITableView e adiciona alguns métodos ao delegate e datasource para implementar a expansão de seções.

Answer (score 2):

## Resposta curta

Não use menu lateral.<sup>[1](https://lmjabreu.com/post/why-and-how-to-avoid-hamburger-menus/), [2](http://blog.manbolo.com/2014/06/30/apple-on-hamburger-menus) (ambos em inglês)</sup>

## Resposta longa

O fato de você usar um `SWRevealViewController` é irrelevante. Como o Rafael Leão disse basta mexer em sua `UITableView`. Uma solução bem simples é trocar suas *cells* por *section headers* que no tap mostram as *cells* da seção.

Comment: Você linka duas vezes para o mesmo post em um blog.

Comment: Não, acabei de arrumar, obrigado.

Comment: Recomendo também alertar que as referências são em inglês. :)

Comment: Sim, boa ideia :)

Comment: @fpg1503  li os artigos e achei muito interessante, agora entendo que não e tão eficiente e que alguns usuários podem não advinhar que existe um menu escondido. a questão em si e que eu peguei um projeto para desenvolver  e nele esta definido que o menu seja desta forma, irei testar a solução do Rafael Leão